# How to flexibly change theme of highcharts (using gradients)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, theming

How do we create advanced themes for highcharts? Documentation on the following link (http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use) is not enough.

I am trying to create a theme that is similar to the following link:
https://app.simplymeasured.com/viewer/acpsb7gp68xdpxnb2sufahdtvmfcmu/357342

Basically how do we use gradients for bars and background? if it is not an easy job does any body know some ready themes?

Comment: See this answer regarding bar gradients: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472361/styling-bar-colors-in-highcharts-with-a-gradient-issue/9478898#9478898