# ColorAxis in percentage bar. Approach. Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to use ColorAxis in a bar?

It seems that only works with maps, I could do an approach iterating the data and setting the colour, do you know any tool to get the stops?

or Any better idea?

```
colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        minColor: '#a50022',
        maxColor: '#007340',
        gridLineColor: '#000000',
        stops: [
            [0, '#a50022'],
            [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
            [1, '#007340']
        ],
    },
```

Comment: It is common only with the highmaps, not with bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

You could have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/A7zSf/ and this [Styling bar colors in Highcharts with a gradient issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472361/styling-bar-colors-in-highcharts-with-a-gradient-issue) for some additional resources.

Alternatively you could style the `plotBackground` with a gradient to match your value ranges. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.plotBackgroundColor

Comment: I am not sure if I get it, shouldnt this be different colours then? http://jsfiddle.net/S3QFJ/4/

Comment: No, `Chart` doesn't have a property called `color`

Comment: This is different colours http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/S3QFJ/7/ but it won't work on a basis like you want it to.  The first value of the stops array is a floating point between 0 and 1 where 0 and 1 are the extremes of the gradient.

Comment: ummm..., no, what I want its to have it with different colours if its value its 30%, than if its 31% than if its 38%

Comment: yes but the gradient is applied the same across all bars. So you specifying stop 0 = red, stop 0.5 yellow and stop 1 green will mean *every* bar gets red,yellow and green.  Have a look at what I just demod

Comment: Yes, yes, understood, but that is not what I would like, I would like the colour of the bar changing depending on its value

Comment: That is exactly why i'm explaining to you that it's not possible!  Just iterate over your data and set the color accordingly.