# Gradient background bars in Highchart bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, gradient

My problem is changing background bars in a highchart bar chart. I can change bars to a specific color like below but I want to make it gradient.

In this code I used red color (FF0000) in chart options. How to change it for gradient backgroud?

**HTML :**

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**JS :**

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
        },
        colors: [
            '#ff0000'
            ],
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            title: {
                text: 'Percentage',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 80,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Year 1800',
            data: [10, 31, 63, 3, 28]
        }]
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbgchLt2/)

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472361/styling-bar-colors-in-highcharts-with-a-gradient-issue) can help you

Comment: It helps me, thanks @SimonM.

Answer (score 1):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neville/Lx8zeety/1/)

Please refer above fiddle to check the results

First, declare a gradient as per Highcharts

```
const color_grad1 = {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                    [0, '#fdfc47'],
                    [1, '#24fe41']
                                    ]
                        };
```

Then use gradient as follows:

```
data: [{y: 10, color: color_grad1}, 31, 63, 3, 28]
```